# Calculation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Here I try to reduce the number of leave limit by the amount of leave 4-12, but every time I want to reduce the amount is always only the previous number is reduced

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

controller

```
public function approved($id)
{
    $data = array(
        'status'=> 'approved'
    );
    $this->Mcuti->update($id, $data);
    $operasi = array(
        'jumlah_bc'=> 'jumlah_bc'-'jumlah_cuti'
    );
    $this->Mcuti->pengurangan($id, $operasi);
    redirect('backend/cuti/preview');
}
```

Model

```
public function pengurangan($id, $operasi)
{
    $this->db->query('UPDATE batas_cuti JOIN cuti ON batas_cuti.nik=cuti.nik SET batas_cuti.jumlah_bc=batas_cuti.jumlah_bc-cuti.jumlah_cuti');
    $query = $this->db->where($id);
    return $query;
}
```